# How to make input field text editable?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem of trying to make the input text field editable.

Currently, I am unable to edit the values of the input text field where i can remove or add new characters to the value in the input text field.

I have set the values statically in the state objects but I also want to edit the state values from the input text field.

How can I edit the code below to make the value editable?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Info extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "Jack Sparrow",
      age: "52",
      email: "jacksparrow52@gmail.com"
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let newState = {...this.state};
      newState[e.target.name] = e.target.name
    this.setState({
      ...newState
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Enter your name..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.age} placeholder="Enter your age..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder="Enter your email..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <h3>Output states:</h3>
        <p id="name">Entered Name: {this.state.name}</p>
        <p id="age">Entered Age: {this.state.age}</p>
        <p id="email">Entered Email: {this.state.email}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

render(<Info />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state to the target input name. Fix this line

```
newState[e.target.name] = e.target.name
```

with (notice `e.target.value`)

```
newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your input field like this, Add input field name and bind handle Change inside the input field. Now you do not want to bind handle Change in constructor.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Enter your name..." onChange={this.handelChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
```

Now replace handle change function,

```
     handelChange(field, event) {
    this.setState({
      [field]: event.target.value
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I hope this helps, I created a codesandbox with this solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-inputs-m4fqk6?file=/src/App.tsx:256-2201

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface infoProfile {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const App = () => {
  const [editCancel, setEditCancel] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<infoProfile>({
    name: "Anakin Skywalker",
    email: "anakin@empire.com"
  });

  const onClick = (): void => {
    setValue({ email: value.email, name: value.name });
    setEditCancel(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Editable Inputs</h1>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setEditCancel(!editCancel)}>
          {editCancel ? "Cancel" : "Edit"}
        </button>
        {editCancel && <button onClick={onClick}>Save</button>}
      </div>
      {!editCancel && (
        <div>
          <h2>Name</h2>
          <div>{value.name}</div>
          <h2>Email</h2>
          <div>{value.email}</div>
        </div>
      )}
      {editCancel && (
        <div>
          <h2>Name</h2>
          <input
            value={value.name}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setValue({ name: e.target.value, email: value.email })
            }
          />
          <h2>Email</h2>
          <input
            value={value.email}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setValue({ email: e.target.value, name: value.name })
            }
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31309841)

Comment: @Lies thank you for the feedback, I updated my post hopefully this time it looks better, if you can up-vote answer that would be terrific, thanks again !!